# C++ standard output format

Tags: c++, format, cout

I want to create a C++ console application that print some text to different parts of the console. For example in QBasic you can use:

```
locate(8,5)
print "hi"
```

And hi would be printed in column 8 line 5. In C++ when I use cout it always prints on the next line, and begins printing in the first column.
Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ command line software](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623669/c-command-line-software), also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458655.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep the terminal from scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458655/how-to-keep-the-terminal-from-scrolling)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712741/what-libraries-are-needed-for-graphics-like-vim-or-nano.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++ *itself* does not have this feature, it's I/O model is a fairly simple, sequential one.

If you want to do fancy cursor positioning, you'll need to output (for example) control characters which your *terminal* will recognise as special commands (such as ANSI or VT escape sequences), or use a library like curses (see [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) here) which can do a lot of the grunt work for you, not just cursor positioning but also things like text mode windows and so forth.

Comment: Tkanks. Also do you know if standard C++ supports changing color of text in standard output?

Comment: @Topo : No, it doesn't. You have to use a library like ncurses.

Comment: No, you can use colors without an additional library!  Using [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).  This is exactly how color in the console works.

Comment: @Gandaro, the question was if _standard_ C++ supports this. It does not. C++ is quite capable of sending arbitrary character sequences to an output device but C++ itself doesn't mandate how they're interpreted. There's no guarantee that the device will understand ANSI escape sequences, or VT100 commands. It may be simply a dumb terminal with very limited intelligence. Curses abstract all that away from you - it's not _necessary_ if you know the terminal capabilities but it still makes things much easier.

Comment: You are right...  Using curses there is a nice abstraction layer.  But you *can*, if you want. ;)

Answer (score 2):

A library, like [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html) can help you do this.